# MVC Grid with Checkbox Control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have to implement one good looking Grid in MVC4+Razor.Till Now I have done by using Table tr and td Since i am new to MVC So can someone suggest me how to change my code to New Good UI Grid as well as i want one checkbox on every row for deleting that particular record Can some one help me to implement this i am attaching my code.Note I am getting the values from ADO.NET DB So please send me with code for Grid as well as checkbox in every record and how to fire Delete on that checkbox

**MODEL**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Employee_Mgmt_System.Models
{
    public class AdminHomeScreen
    {
        public string EmpID { get; set; }
        public string EmpName { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }


    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Employee_Mgmt_System.Models;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Employee_Mgmt_System.Controllers
{
    public class AdminHomeScreenController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /AdminHomeScreen/

        public ActionResult AdminHomeScreen()
        {

                return View();


        }

    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Employee_Mgmt_System.Models.AdminHomeScreen>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Admin Home Screen";
}

<h2> Admin Home Screen</h2>
<div id="AdminScreen" style="background-color:azure">
<table border="1" style="border-color:black">
    <tr>
        <td style="font:25px">EMPID</td>
        <td style="font:25px">Employee Name</td>
        <td style="font:25px">Country</td>
        <td style="font:25px">State</td>
        <td style="font:25px">City</td>
        <td style="font:25px">EmailAddress</td>
    </tr>
         @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="font:25px">@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.EmpID)</td>
                <td style="font:25px">@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.EmpName)</td>
                <td style="font:25px">@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.CountryName)</td>
                <td style="font:25px">@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.StateName)</td>
                <td style="font:25px">@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.CityName)</td>
                <td style="font:25px">@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.EmailAddress)</td>
            </tr>
        }

</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use @Html.CheckboxFor(x=>x.item.EmpName)